# jquery hide/show work only for 1st element of foreach

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hide/Show work fine for first element of foreach cycle in asp.net view, but for another elements did not work.

*Script*

```
 $('#SelectedContainer').hide();
 $(".data").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#BrowseContainer').hide();
    $('#SelectedContainer').show();
 });
 $("#goback").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#SelectedContainer').hide();
    $('#BrowseContainer').show();
 });
```

*HTML*:

```
foreach (var ....){
<table border="1">
    <tr class="tableBody">
        <td>
            <div id="SelectedContainer" class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div><a id="goback" href="#">hide</a></div>
                    Test
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="BrowseContainer" class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row-fluid container">
                    <a class="data" href="#">Show</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
}
```

What is my problem?

Comment: Id's must be unique. because that you hide/show does not work as you expected. Also show us your html, for more help.

Comment: I added html in top post

Comment: change the SelectedContainer and BrowseContainer id to class. and change your javascript accordingly

Comment: also the id="goback" should be unique to each table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs must be unique, You should use common classes instead. You should use [`$.fn.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) then you can use [`$.fn.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to target desired element.

Here in the example I have used classes instead of IDs.

*HTML*

```
<table border="1">
    <tr class="tableBody">
        <td>
            <div class="SelectedContainer container-fluid">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div><a class="goback" href="#">hide</a></div>
                    Test
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="BrowseContainer container-fluid">
                <div class="row-fluid container">
                    <a class="data" href="#">Show</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

*Script*

```
$('.SelectedContainer').hide();
$(".data").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var table = $(this).closest('table');
    table.find('.BrowseContainer').hide();
    table.find('.SelectedContainer').show();
});

$(".goback").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var table = $(this).closest('table');
    table.find('.SelectedContainer').hide();
    table.find('.BrowseContainer').show();
});
```

Comment: Thanks to you and other commentators for the help and tips